# Alertmanager is not sending alerts to receivers

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am using **prometheus** without docker using **blackbox exporter** to probe icmp targets and **alertmanager** for alerting on a mac.

The test I do is simple, toggle the connectivity of the target by adding-removing the lan cable. With this setup I am able to see the alert in prometheus when target is not reachable and it clears when target is reachable.

I try to receive **smtp** and **webhook** notifications, but both are not working when the alert state is "FIRING".

Here is alertmanager.yml

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 2m
  smtp_require_tls: false

route:
  group_by: ['instance', 'severity']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 10s
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: 'team-1'
receivers:
- name: 'team-1'
  email_configs:
  - to: xxx@xxx.com
    from: xxx@gmail.com
    smarthost: smtp.gmail.com:587
    auth_username: "xxx@gmail.com"
    auth_identity: "xxx@gmail.com"
    auth_password: "xxx" ----> app token
  webhook_configs:
  - url: "http://xxx.ngrok.io/api/feedback/alertManager"
```

Here is the screenshot of prometheus alerts with its config and active alerts
[alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txZj1.png)

I also observed that by adding *--log.level=debug* to prometheus and blackbox there is good amount of logging activity. But same is not applicable for alertmanager as I don't see any floating logs.

Also when the alert is actually Active, the alertmanager api on querying with postman returns empty array of alerts.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: Looks like I missed adding alerting config to prometheus configuration `alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9093`